# convert precisely azimuth degrees to human

Tags: javascript, human-readable, azimuth

I'm write this bit of code to convert azimuth degrees to human redable, but the conversion is not more accurate, in cases of degrees is slightly smaller than 360.

```
function azimutHuman(ang) {     //can be 0 - 360

    var azimuthHumans = [
              'Nord','Nord-NE','Nord-Est','Est-NE',
              'Est','Est-SE','Sud-Est','Sud-SE',
              'Sud','Sud-SO','Sud-Ovest','Ovest-SO',
              'Ovest','Ovest-SO','Nord-Ovest','Nord-NO'];

    return azimuthHumans[ Math.round(ang/22.5) ];
}
```

for example:

```
azimutHuman(350);   //return undefined instead of "Nord"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

350 -> 360  = 0->10  : 360 is north as will as 0 .

so you need to add an element "Nord" again  .try this function now :

```
function azimutHuman(ang) {     //can be 0 - 360

    var azimuthHumans = [
              'Nord','Nord-NE','Nord-Est','Est-NE',
              'Est','Est-SE','Sud-Est','Sud-SE',
              'Sud','Sud-SO','Sud-Ovest','Ovest-SO',
              'Ovest','Ovest-SO','Nord-Ovest','Nord-NO','Nord'];

    return azimuthHumans[ Math.round(ang/22.5) ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round(350/22.5) = 16` Your array at index 16 is undefined. Add a 16th element to it, `Nord` again should work